# What are some good sources for Pages and Keynote templates?

Tags: pages, keynote, iwork

It doesn't matter whether they are for free or for purchase as long as they are compatible.

Comment: @grg What is the point of putting a question on hold after it has been sitting here for 8 years?

Comment: @Tom This is an extremely broad request for links and recommendations to off-site resources; these regularly attracts spam, which is what occurred here with a spam answer posted today. Questions are judged on their suitability for site scope regardless of date, it just happens that this question was brought to attention due to the spam.

Comment: Also - we’re trying to be clear what makes an off site resource question. See the updated close notes and please head to [meta] for discussions on these in general as well as in specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best commercial packages of themes for the iWork apps, in my experience, are those from [Jumsoft.](http://www.jumsoft.com/)(under Design) They produce themes for both Pages and Keynote, as well as animation and art packs.

For free templates, [iWorkCommunity](http://www.iworkcommunity.com) has a ton of Pages templates, and some decent Numbers templates as well for basic use. [KeynoteUser](http://www.keynoteuser.com/resources/) also produces commercial themes, in addition to having some freebies, and an excellent blog and collection of links for other sources of high quality stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. You can find some nice examples on Themeforest, they should have a big list of such items.
http://wisset.com/premium-keynote-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Klariti has SDLC and business templates over but these are for professionals.

http://klariti.com/apple-iwork-templates/